# Product description not displayed Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I encountered such a problem. There are products on my website that were already in the database and everything works correctly with them
But when creating a new book, I want to add properties to it
But they are not displayed. What could be the problem, please help.

**form.php** - page where values ​​for the book are set

```
@extends('auth.layouts.master')

@isset($offer)
    @section('title', 'Edit Offer ' . $offer->name)
@else
    @section('title', 'Create Offer')
@endisset

@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @isset($offer)
            <h1>Edit Offer <b>{{ $offer->name }}</b></h1>
        @else
            <h1>Add Offer</h1>
        @endisset

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            @isset($offer)
            action="{{ route('offers.update', [$book, $offer]) }}"
            @else
            action="{{ route('offers.store', $book) }}"
            @endisset
        >
            <div>
                @isset($offer)
                    @method('PUT')
                @endisset
                @csrf

                    <div class="input-group row">
                        <label for="price" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Price: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            @include('auth.layouts.error', ['fieldName' => 'price'])
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"
                                value="@isset($offer){{ $offer->price }}@endisset">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group row">
                        <label for="count" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Quantity: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            @include('auth.layouts.error', ['fieldName' => 'count'])
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="count"
                                value="@isset($offer){{ $offer->count }}@endisset">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                @foreach ($book->properties as $property)
                    <div class="input-group row">
                        <label for="property_id[{{ $property->id }}]" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ $property->name }}: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select name="property_id[{{ $property->id }}]" class="form-control">
                                @foreach($property->propertyOptions as $propertyOption)
                                    <option value="{{ $propertyOption->id }}"
                                        @isset($offer)
                                        @if($offer->propertyOptions->contains($propertyOption->id))
                                            selected
                                        @endif
                                        @endisset
                                    >{{ $propertyOption->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

                <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**index.blade.php** - page where you can interact with parameters

```
    @extends('auth.layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Book Offers')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Book Offers</h1>
        <h2>{{ $book->name }}</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    #
                </th>
                <th>
                    Book Offer (Properties)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Actions
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($offer as $offe)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $offe->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $offe->propertyOptions->map->name->implode(', ') }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <form action="{{ route('offers.destroy', [$book, $offe]) }}" method="POST">
                                <a class="btn btn-success" type="button" href="{{ route('offers.show', [$book, $offe]) }}">Open</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" type="button" href="{{ route('offers.edit', [$book, $offe]) }}">Edit</a>
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {{ $offer->links() }}
        <a class="btn btn-success" type="button"
        href="{{ route('offers.create', $book) }}">Add Book Offer</a>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/books/{book}/offers', 'OfferController');
Route::resource('properties', 'PropertyController');
Route::resource('coupons', 'CouponController');
Route::resource('properties/{property}/property-options', 'PropertyOptionController');
```

**Property.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Traits\Translatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Property extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Translatable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'name_pt'];

    public function propertyOptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PropertyOption::class);
    }

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }

}
```

**Book.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Traits\Translatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Book extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, Translatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code', 'price', 'category_id', 'description', 'image', 'hit', 'new', 'recommend', 'count', 'name_pt',
        'description_pt', 'pages', 'author', 'isbn'
    ];
    protected $table = 'books';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'property_book')->withTimestamps();
    }
   }
```

**OfferController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\OfferRequest;
use App\Models\Book;
use App\Models\Offer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OfferController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(Book $book)
    {
        $offer = $book->offers()->paginate(10);
        // dd($offer);
        return view('auth.offers.index', compact('offer', 'book'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create(Book $book)
    {   
        // dd( $book);
        return view('auth.offers.form', compact('book'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(OfferRequest $request, Book $book)
    {
        $params = $request->all();
        $params['book_id'] = $request->book->id;
        $offer = Offer::create($params);
        $offer->propertyOptions()->sync($request->property_id);
        // dd( $offer);
        return redirect()->route('offers.index', $book);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Book $book, Offer $offer)
    {   
        // dd($offer);
        return view('auth.offers.show', compact('book', 'offer'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Book $book, Offer $offer)
    {   
        return view('auth.offers.form', compact('book', 'offer'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Book $book, Offer $offer)
    {
        $params = $request->all();
        $params['book_id'] = $request->book->id;
        $offer->update($params);
        // dd($offer);
        $offer->propertyOptions()->sync($request->property_id);
        return redirect()->route('offers.index', $book);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Book $book, Offer $offer)
    {
        $offer->delete();
        return redirect()->route('offers.index', $book);
    }
}
```

Photos of problem
https://imgur.com/a/IqIfaXl

Comment: i would try to be more accurate about where the problem is

Comment: Maybe `$book->with('properties')->offers()->paginate(10);` ?

Comment: @PaulT. Error: Property [offers] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: when i use previous code, when I go to view product properties, I see this https://imgur.com/a/12VD8EV

Comment: Ok, it was just a thought. I find that I have use `with` sometimes to get the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there. I just rewrote this function:

```
public function store(BookRequest $request)
{
    $params = $request->all();
    unset($params['image']);

    $book = Book::create($params);

    $book->properties()->sync($request->property_id);

    if ($request->has('image')) {
        $book->image = $request->file('image')->store('books');
        $book->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('books.index');
}
```